# Apache: cURL: ssl3_get_record:wrong version number for apache2 ssl

Tags: ssl, curl, apache2.4

I have a server with 2 Magento sites running simultaneously. Site 1 works fine under SSL, while site 2 returns an error whenever I visit it.

I tried to test the website using cURL:

```
curl -v https://example2-domain.com/
```

The cURL throws this error:

```
*   Trying 97.74.223.135...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example2-domain.com (97.74.233.135) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Here's the Apache VirtualHost blocks for reference:

```
<VirtualHost 97.74.233.135:8080>
    ServerName www.example-domain.com
    ServerAlias example-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example-domain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /home/example/public_html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 97.74.233.135:8080>
    ServerName example-domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example2/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example-domain2.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example2/public_html/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /home/example2/public_html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 97.74.233.135:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example-domain.com
    ServerName www.example-domain.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-domain.com-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-domain.com-ssl-access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6081/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/example-domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/example-domain-key.txt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/example-domain.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 97.74.233.135:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example-domain2.com
    ServerName example-domain2.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-domain2.com-ssl-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-domain2.com-ssl-access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6081/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/example-domain2.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/example-domain2-key.txt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/example-domain2.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

In case you're wondering what sits on port 6081, Varnish is configured to sit on that port.

Can someone please care to enlighten me as to why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: This usually indicates that the server isn't responding with any expected TLS data. Have you checked the apache logs? Could it be that you are pointing to some files that don't exist and therefor apache is not able set up TLS connections? It might be a case of you replacing the actual host names with example names, but the `SSLCertificateFile` property for `example-domain2.com` contains an extra `.com` - ie. `/ssl/example-domain2.com.crt` while the `www.example.domain.com` configuration for the same contains no `.com` - ie. `/ssl/example-domain.crt`

Comment: I've checked the paths for the certificate files and their corresponding names, everything is in proper order. What's bugging me is that their VirtualHost blocks are completely the same, except for filenames and paths, yet the other one doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue when working on an **Apache2** web server on **Ubuntu 20.04** when working to set up SSL for a website.

Each time I run a curl request:

```
curl https://corebanking.test.vggdev.com
```

OR

```
curl https://my-website.com:443
```

I get the error:

```
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I checked my configuration file for the website (`my-website.conf`) and it seemed fine.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I figured that I did not have the configuration file for the website (`my-website.conf`) in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory. So the configuration was not enabled.

All I had to do was to symlink the `my-website.conf` to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-website.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-website
```

Next, I listed the contents of the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory to be sure that the configuration file for the website (`my-website.conf`) was there:

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Finally, I restarted the apache2 web server:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: You could also enable a site configuration by simply running `sudo a2ensite my-website` and then restarting apache.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was my NAT configuration pointing to the wrong internal port. UI allow writing source/dist ports with coma separator but it was not associative (source=`80,443` and dest=`80,443` redirect all packets to `80`).

In this scenario, Apache configuration was valid and access logs keep trace of the request but with no more information about the ports configuration issue. The response was a code 400 for Bad request :

```
x.x.x.x - - [25/Aug/2021:09:06:23 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

BONUS : For an easier debugging process of TLS, I used `openssl s_client` instead of `curl` for checking SSL configuration

```
openssl s_client -connect example2-domain.com:443
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the domain was pointing to the wrong server in the first place! That's why the errors are showing. The configurations were all correct after pointing the domain's A record to the correct server.